# Thematic maps in R

Tags: r

An interesting example within Shiny is [US map](http://shiny.rstudio.com/tutorial/lesson5/). I like to implement it for instance for the Postal codes in the Netherlands [Dutch shapes](http://www.imergis.nl/asp/47.asp) and create a simple thematic map.

```
library(maptools)
readshp<-readShapeSpatial("C:/R/census-app/ESRI-PC4-2015R1.shp")
```

The variable on which I like to create a map is added in the Dbasefile behind the shape, but after:

```
map("readshp", fill = TRUE, col = fills, 
resolution = 0, lty = 0, projection = "polyconic",
myborder = 0, mar = c(0,0,0,0))
```

R shows the error:

*Error in get(dbname) : object 'readshpMapEnv' not found*

How can we fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I guess it's due to the quotes. Remove the quotes around your object. Try:

`map(readshp, fill = TRUE, col = fills, 
resolution = 0, lty = 0, projection = "polyconic",
myborder = 0, mar = c(0,0,0,0))`

Besides.. next time "include just enough code to allow others to reproduce the problem.." see [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) ;)